# Facebook access_token automatic renewal

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have Facebook login database in my system. I am storing Long-Lived user access token with UserID to my database and I need to renew the token before it expires. I have found a [page in Facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension#long-via-code) and I tried to renew the token by following the steps. **Facebook returns different access token, but expiration time is still the same.**

This is what I've got: (I am using Facebook's PHPSDK 5.0.0)

```
$t = $this->access_token;
if ($t && $t->getExpiresAt()->getTimestamp() <= strtotime('+14 days'))
{
    $oauth = $this->fb->getOAuth2Client();
    $code = $oauth->getCodeFromLongLivedAccessToken($t, $this->redrect_urls['renew']);
    $t = $oauth->getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $this->redrect_urls['renew']);
    if ($t)
    {
        $this->database->table($this->config->getTable('facebook-logins'))
            ->where('user_id', $this->user_id)
            ->update(array(
                'expires_at'    => $t->getExpiresAt(),
                'access_token'  => $t->getValue(),
                'facebook_name' => $this->getUserAccount()['name'],
            ));
    }
}
```

What should I do to renew the token expiration date? Is it possible to do this token renewal fully automatically without bothering the user to click on link or whatever?

Thanks for any tips,
TheKronnY

Comment: it if of course not possible to renew a token without user interaction. that would make the whole point of epiring tokens useless.

Comment: @luschn, so have you got any idea how to renew them? With user interaction?

Comment: What exactly you want to accomplish by saving the access token of the users?

Comment: I need to send them notifications based on various system events.

Comment: Is it a canvass app and with notifications you mean facebook notification?

Comment: @SahilMittal Well it is canvas app, but it is primarily used as normal web app outside of Facebook. So I do not know how to solve this.

Comment: ONLY canvas apps can send the facebook notifications, normal web apps cannot! Another thing- for facebook notification you are not required user access token, but APP ACCESS TOKEN which is static and never expires.